A grid of Primes
I have a 3x3 grid for which I want to populate with DISTINCT primes (smaller primes the better). For which the SUM of each row, each column, the 2-diagonals (largest ones), and lastly the entire 9 cells, still result in primes.  Find a set with the TOTAL sum of all 9 cells to be MINIMIZED. (Smallest Prime)
I started using FindInstance, but then realized that it does not support the usage of PrimeQ as a condition (this is well referenced).
Then I thought of using Select, but that will need to hold a list of 9 Primes and convolute them in triplets like Tuples[Prime[Range[20]], 9] , say to test with the first 20 primes, this blows out the memory right away.
Maybe use 3 sets of different Tuples? Then try and mix them according to the rules above? Not sure.
Or maybe I should be using MapThread somehow for this with input primes lists and somehow tie it together to fit the rules?
The most compact solution is much appreciated!
P.S. This is not exactly a magic-square as the records do not add up to a constant sum, but rather they add up to new primes.

If the rows sum to a prime $p$, then the total of all 9 elements cannot be prime because it will be $3p$ . Edit: nevermind I forgot the rows don't have to sum to the same prime

I just realized I probably should've asked a clarifying question before I posted an answer; do all 9 primes need to be unique?

Yes all primes are distinct. and the 2 diagonals are the largest ones.

Thanks, I also changed the selection criterion for the smallest matrix to be by the total, instead of by the smallest largest prime (it doesn't effect the output in any way, the minimal matrix is the same in both cases).

Since such cases are quite dense random trial is enough.
mat = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};

eq = {Total /@ mat, Total /@ Transpose[mat], Tr[mat], 
    Tr[Reverse /@ mat], Total@Flatten@mat} // Flatten;

Do[ra = RandomPrime[100, 9]; 
 If[And @@ PrimeQ[eq /. Thread[Flatten@mat -> ra]], 
  Print[MatrixForm@Partition[ra, 3]]], 10000]



This is with the smallest possible sum 127 (sum of the smallest nine primes except 2).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 7 & 5 & 19 \\
 13 & 11 & 29 \\
 17 & 3 & 23 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Hey I don't want random Primes, I want one with the TOTAL SUM to be Minimized!

@Steve237 I think it's still a good answer. I think the way the question was originally asked made it seem like minimizing the total sum/size of the primes was a secondary goal, and not the primary goal of just finding a 3x3 matrix that satisfied the conditions (not that I think it was a bad question, I was not the downvoter).

@azerbajdzan : Can you update your script to grab smallest Primes?

@Steve237 Since RandomPrime[100, 9] generates primes smaller than 100 isn't it minimizing?  You can change 100 with smaller values if you wish.

@azerbajdzan Ah, but if you run with with small enough bounds, RandomPrime[40, 9] for example, you get several duplicate or repeat primes, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to constrain the input down to 9 distinct primes (my imperative programming brain struggles with Mathematica)

@AdamWhite Use ra = DeleteDuplicates[RandomPrime[40, 100]][[1 ;; 9]] in my code.

@azerbajdzan Why is the duplicate using range of 40-->100 ? How does that work.... Do we use this AFTER this line also?  ra = DeleteDuplicates[RandomPrime[100, 9]] so we need both lines?

@azerbajdzan ahh I see my mistake. I need to do the permutations of my IntegerPartitions of primes as well. I'll modify my answer for this but cool that you found the minimum.

@Steve237 Replace ra = RandomPrime[100, 9]; with ra = DeleteDuplicates[RandomPrime[40, 100]][[1 ;; 9]];.

Also the output can potantially repeat different arrangements of the same 9 numbers! Example use this:  Do[ra = DeleteDuplicates[RandomPrime[29, 100]][[1 ;; 9]];   and you will see 9 sets of the same numbers!

@Steve237 Of course, RandomPrime[29, 100] generates 100 random primes that are less than or equal to 29. There are exactly 9 such primes except of 2.

@azerbajdzan FWIW you can decrease the upper bound for the random primes each time you find a solution example here

Assuming "the 2 diagonals" means the diagonal and anti-diagonal
I first start by finding IntegerPartitions of the first 7 primes that consist of 3 primes:
rowCands = 
  Table[IntegerPartitions[Prime@k, {3}, Prime@Range@k], {k, 7}];
rowCands = Flatten[rowCands, 1];

I then generate the length-3 subsets of these candidate rows to make 3x3 matrices that have rows that already sum to primes:
subs = Subsets[rowCands, {3}];

I then create tests for the sum of the columns, diagonal/anti-diagonal, and total:
columnTest[mat_] := And @@ PrimeQ@Total@mat

diagTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Tr@mat && PrimeQ@Tr@Reverse@mat

totalTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Total@Flatten@mat

Then select the matrices that meet all the conditions. You could do each of the tests separately in nested Ifs to save computation but for clarity I do them all at once in one bigTest:
bigTest[mat_] := columnTest[mat] && diagTest[mat] && totalTest[mat]

pass = Table[
  If[bigTest[cand], cand, Nothing]
  , {cand, subs}];

And then select the one with the smallest total:
best = TakeSmallestBy[pass, Total@Flatten@# &, 1] // First


And we see the indeed the rows sum to {11,13,17}
The columns sum to {19, 11, 11}
The diagonal and antidiagonal sum to {13,13}
And all 9 sum to 41
Which are all prime.
Putting this all together:
rowCands = 
  Table[IntegerPartitions[Prime@k, {3}, Prime@Range@k], {k, 7}];
rowCands = Flatten[rowCands, 1];
subs = Subsets[rowCands, {3}];

columnTest[mat_] := And @@ PrimeQ@Total@mat

diagTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Tr@mat && PrimeQ@Tr@Reverse@mat

totalTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Total@Flatten@mat

bigTest[mat_] := columnTest[mat] && diagTest[mat] && totalTest[mat]

pass = Table[If[bigTest[cand], cand, Nothing], {cand, subs}];

best = TakeSmallestBy[pass, Total@Flatten@# &, 1] // First


Add-on
I forgot to clarify whether all 9 primes need to be unique. If this is the case, then we can increase our search bound k for finding partitions of the first k primes, select only the partitions with 3 unique primes, and then select the 3x3 subsets that consist of 9 unique primes:
rowCands = 
  Table[IntegerPartitions[Prime@k, {3}, Prime@Range@k], {k, 20}];
rowCands = Flatten[rowCands, 1];
uniqueRows = Select[rowCands, CountDistinct[#] == 3 &];

subs = Subsets[uniqueRows, {3}];
uniqueSubs = Select[subs, CountDistinct@Flatten@# == 9 &];


columnTest[mat_] := And @@ PrimeQ@Total@mat

diagTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Tr@mat && PrimeQ@Tr@Reverse@mat

totalTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Total@Flatten@mat

bigTest[mat_] := columnTest[mat] && diagTest[mat] && totalTest[mat]


pass = Table[If[bigTest[cand], cand, Nothing], {cand, uniqueSubs}];

best = TakeSmallestBy[pass, Total@Flatten@# &, 1] // First



2nd add-on
After seeing @azerbajdzan 's answer, I realized I forgot that the rows need to be permuted as well, since each row's ordering effects column/diagonal sum.
I now iteratively increase kMax until I find a candidate space, and then find the matrix with the minimum sum:
uniqueSubs = {};
kMax = 6;
While[uniqueSubs == {},
 kMax++;
 rowCands = 
  Table[IntegerPartitions[Prime@k, {3}, Prime@Range@k], {k, kMax}];
 rowCands = Flatten[rowCands, 1];
 uniqueRows = Select[rowCands, CountDistinct[#] == 3 &];
 (*all unique rows must be permuted*)
 permedRows = Flatten[Permutations /@ uniqueRows, 1];
 subs = Subsets[permedRows, {3}];
 uniqueSubs = Select[subs, CountDistinct@Flatten@# == 9 &];
 ]

columnTest[mat_] := And @@ PrimeQ@Total@mat

diagTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Tr@mat && PrimeQ@Tr@Reverse@mat

totalTest[mat_] := PrimeQ@Total@Flatten@mat

bigTest[mat_] := columnTest[mat] && diagTest[mat] && totalTest[mat]


pass = Table[If[bigTest[cand], cand, Nothing], {cand, uniqueSubs}];

best = TakeSmallestBy[pass, Total@Flatten@# &, 1] // First


Which is just a permutation of @azerbajdzan 's answer.

Thanks @ydd  Where in your code are you using the smallest Primes?

In IntegerPartitions where I create the rows. Since I only calculate the IntegerPartitions for the first 20 primes, the row sums are bounded above by Prime[20], and therefore the total is bounded by 3 Prime[20]  . Increasing the search bound of 20 to something higher will just increase the row sum upper bound, which can only increase the total sum. So the sum is minimal
